# C#, How to convert Object to Class Type

Tags: c#, casting, .net-core-3.1

I am working on .NET CORE application. I have declare an `Object` that I need to cast or convert to `Customer` class type. I have scenario where based on bool value I need to change the type and return that.

`error`

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Object must implement IConvertible
```

`Customer Class`

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Customer GetCutsomer(){
             //
    }
}
```

'Object Casting`

```
public class MyService
{
   public void CastType(){

       Customer obj = new Customer();

       var cus = GetCutsomer();

       Object customer = new Object();

       Convert.ChangeType(customer , cus.GetType());
   }
}
```

Comment: customer is just an object. You can't cast it to customer as it isn't a customer.  You can convert it to a different type but for that (as the runtime states) you need a conversion method implemented in your class. But that make no sense here. An object has no data you can transform to being a customer.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do or why.  If you need a `Customer` instance, why not just create a `Customer` instance?  Why are you creating an `Object` instance?

Comment: I am with mess of someone else code ... and need to decide at run time, tried dynamic but did not work out, it through exception, with conditions I can decide what object to pass, unless there is better solution

Answer (score 4):

You have some choices. Lets make a Customer and loose that fact by assigning to an object variable. And one that isnt a customer to show that case too

```
    object o1 = new Customer();
    object o2 = new String("not a customer");
```

so now we want to get back its 'customer'ness

First we can use `as`

```
    Customer as1 = o1 as Customer;
    Customer as2 = o2 as Customer;
```

- as1 ends up as a valid Customer pointer
- as2 ends up `null` since o2 is not a Customer object

Or we can do a cast

```
    var cast1 = (Customer)o1;
    try {
        var cast2 = (Customer)o2;
    }
    catch {
        Console.WriteLine("nope");
    }
```

- the first one succeeds
- the second one throws and InvalidCast exception

We can also ask about the object using `is`

```
    if (o1 is Customer)
        Console.WriteLine("yup");
    if (o2 is Customer)
        Console.WriteLine("yup");
```

---

This works too (answering question in comment)

```
object o1 = new Customer();
```

now

```
Customer c = (Customer)o1;
```

then later

```
o1 = new Order();
...
Order ord1 = (Order)o1;
```

Ie an Object pointer can point at any object.

This is inheritance at work. All class objects in c# are ultimately derived from Object, you just dont see it in your code. So an Object pointer can point at any class object

Comment: Can we change the object `Object o1 = new Object()` Type at runtime? i.e. a customer object change to let say an order object

Comment: @K.Z you cannot change a Customer object to an Order object. An 'object' pointer like your 'o1' can point at either though

Answer (score -1):

You should simply be able to safely cast any object to a class:

```
var obj = new Object();
var customer = (Customer)obj;
```

Comment: That cast would fail.

Comment: You can cast a class to an object, but you can't just cast an object to any class